# Datatable on row-reorder data oldData and newData is undefined

Tags: javascript, events, datatables-1.10

I am currently rewriting my datatable from CodeIgniter (datatables v1.10.12 and RowReorder v1.1.2) to Laravel 6 (datatables v1.10.20 and RowReorder v1.2.6). On the event 'row-reorder' i need to collect data about the changes. Therefore i use this script.

```
$('#category-table').on('row-reorder.dt', function (dragEvent, data, nodes) {
    var newSequences = [];

    $.each(data, function(key, change) {
        console.log(change);
        newSequences.push({
            id:         $(change.oldData).data('id'),
            sequence:   $(change.newData).data('sequence')
        });
    });

    doThingsWithTheResult(newSequences);
}
```

In the old situation (CodeIgniter) 'change.oldData' and 'change.newData' are filled with the old and new elements that are affected by the 'row-reorder' event but in the new situation (Laravel) both 'change.oldData' and 'change.newData' are 'undefined'.

[image: Old/working situation]
Old/working situation

[image: New/not working situation]

New/ not working situation

What could be the reason why these crucial properties are 'undefined'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

Although it worked out-of-the-box in the old situation in de new situation i needed to add/provide the [rowReorder.dataSrc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowReorder.dataSrc) setting.